# How to search in a 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, search, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner in Python and I want to search in a 2D array.

```
stock_file = [[21345678, 2.30, "Banana"], [12345670, 3.50, "Apple"]]
```

I want the user to enter an eight digit code and then output `"product found"` if it is in the array. I tried the following code:

```
if eight_digit_code in stock_file:
    print("Product found")
else:
    print("product not found")
```

However, the code will not output `"product found"` even if the code matches the one in the array. Is there something wrong with my code?
Please note, I am not trying to find the index of the code. I want to search if the code is in the array or not.

Comment: I recommend Googling your question's title as a final check before posting it. It often yields good results.

Comment: Current "diplicate" target answers a different question. Not quite applicable here.

Comment: Let's abuse power tools: `[21345678, mock.ANY, mock.ANY] in stock_file` says `True` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
>>> stock_file = [[21345678,2.30,'Banana'],[12345670,3.50,'Apple']]
>>> code=int(input('Enter 8 digit code: '))
Enter 8 digit code: 12345670
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x[0]==code, stock_file))
[[12345670, 3.5, 'Apple']]
>>> code=int(input('Enter 8 digit code: '))
Enter 8 digit code: 21345678
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x[0]==code, stock_file))
[[21345678, 2.3, 'Banana']]
>>>
```